# timer doesn't reset in sfml function

Tags: c++, sfml

```
void strzalObcy(sf::Clock clock, sf::Sprite pociskSprite,sf::RenderWindow &window,int przesuniecie ){
    sf::Time timer = clock.getElapsedTime();
    std::cout << timer.asSeconds() << std::endl;
    if (timer.asSeconds() >= 1.0f )
    {
        pociskSprite.setPosition(100,przesuniecie);
        window.draw(pociskSprite);
        przesuniecie+=50;
        clock.restart();
    }
}
```

Unfortunetly my clock doesn't reset, I don't know why, and I don't really know how to fix it :/
Window drew just one time pociskSprite, in 100,50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void strzalObcy(sf::Clock& clock, sf::Sprite pociskSprite,sf::RenderWindow &window,int przesuniecie ){
    sf::Time timer = clock.getElapsedTime();
    std::cout << timer.asSeconds() << std::endl;
    if (timer.asSeconds() >= 1.0f )
    {
        pociskSprite.setPosition(100,przesuniecie);
        window.draw(pociskSprite);
        przesuniecie+=50;
        clock.restart();
    }
}
```

As Hiura said, your function takes a value and not a reference. Use the & to pass reference instead of value.

Answer (score 0):

Your function takes a **value**, not a **reference**, so you reset the copy and not the original one

Comment: @kozi Then just set it as answered (the tick on the left of the answer if I remember correctly). ;-)